# How to check twilio jwt token is correct or not?

Tags: node.js, video, jwt, twilio, token

-This is regarding Twilio Programmable Video. I am successfully creating a new room on the server side and then generating the token and adding the video grant to generate the JWT via PHP.

```
const AccessToken = require('twilio').jwt.AccessToken;
const VideoGrant = AccessToken.VideoGrant;
```

Comment: Hey Satish. Are you able to give a bit more details to your question? Currently I'm not sure what are you asking about. Have a look at this post: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to learn how to ask a good question, one which we would be able to help you with. You could write what are you doing currently in your code (with relevant code samples), what is the current outcome and what is the expected outcome.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.